# Two ggplot with subset in pipe

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I would like to plot two lines in one plot (both has the same axis), but one of the line is subset values from data frame.

I tries this

```
DF%>% ggplot(subset(., Cars == "A"), aes(Dates, sold_A)) +geom_line()+ ggplot(., (Dates, sold_ALL))
```

but this error occurred

```
 object '.' not found
```

Comment: I've never seen a ggplot object added to an existing ggplot. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Wrap the block you want to use the `.` around in brackets. Something like `DF %>% { ggplot(.) + ... ggplot(.)}`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks....It made two separated plots. Is it possible to make one plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You can't add a ggplot object to a ggplot object:

(2) Try taking the subset out of the call to ggplot.

```
DF %>% 
    subset(Cars == "A") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Dates, sold_A)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_line(data = DF, aes(Dates, sold_ALL))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding how ggplot works. If we are attempting to do it your way, we could do:

```r
DF %>% {ggplot(subset(., Cars == "A"), aes(Dates, sold_A)) +
        geom_line(colour = "red") +
        geom_line(data = subset(., Cars == "B"), colour = "blue") +
        lims(y = c(0, 60))}
```

[image]

But it would be easier and better to map the variable `Cars` to the colour aesthetic, so your plot would be as simple as:

```r
DF %>% ggplot(aes(Dates, sold_A, color = Cars)) + geom_line() + lims(y = c(0, 60))
```

[image]

Note that as well as being simpler code, we get the legend for free.

---

**Data**

Obviously, we didn't have your data for this question, but here is a constructed data set with the same name and same column variables:

```r
set.seed(1)

Dates  <- rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "day", length = 20), 2)
Cars   <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20)
sold_A <- rpois(40, rep(c(20, 40), each = 20))

DF <- data.frame(Dates, Cars, sold_A)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one plot, you would need to remove `ggplot(., aes(Dates, sold_ALL))` and wrap directly into a structure like `geom_line(data=., aes(Dates, sold_ALL))`. Then, use the sage advice from **@MrFlick**. Here an example using `iris` data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Example
iris %>% 
  {ggplot(subset(., Species == "setosa"), aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()+
      geom_point(data=.,aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width),color='blue')}
```

Output:

[image]

The `ggplot(., aes(Dates, sold_ALL))` is creating a new canvas and the new plot.